# Android admob works with new app, but I cant seem to implement ads into a finished app

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have followed https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start and made an banner ad show up fine but when I go to my finished app to try and change the exact same pieces of code it doesn't want to show up. I'm interested to know if anyone has encountered this or can think of something I am missing. This is the relevant logcat when I test the finished app with the code changed:

06-25 19:43:42.419    7054-7054/com.testing.testApp I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.

06-25 19:43:44.391    7054-7054/com.testing.testApp I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.

06-25 19:43:44.421    7054-7054/com.testing.testApp I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.

Comment: So more log. What does it say when the ad response is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
activity_home.xml    
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<!-- container for banner -->

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bannerContainerLayoutHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
</RelativeLayout>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Try this code i hope your problem will solve...

Comment: what does this line do <android:layout_above="@+id/layoutBottom">

Comment: That line is mistacally written by me now this work fine try it

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
 import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity  {

private RelativeLayout bannerContainerLayoutHome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
 bannerContainerLayoutHome =   
 (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bannerContainerLayoutHome);     
showBannerAd();
    }
/**
 * show ad banner at footer
 * 
 */
private void showBannerAd()
{
    AdView adView = new AdView(HomeActivity.this);
    //cal method to show banner add


        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);


    adView.setAdUnitId("PUT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID");
    bannerContainerLayoutHome.addView(adView);

    AdRequest adRequest = new 
    AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secur    
     e.ANDROID_ID)).build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help im just getting an error with this line: bannerContainerLayoutHome.addView(adView);

Comment: With the following line, is anything missing, i seem to still be having an error: bannerContainerLayoutHome =   
     (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bannerContainerLayoutHome);